# Spatial clustering/sampling in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I have a spatial data frame in R. we have a class imbalance problem so I want to be able to remove the positive cases (our response variable is binary and positive is approx 10% of the dataset) and then select a portion of the negative cases to combat the class imbalance in the model. I want to select negative cases that are closely related spatially and I am really struggling to figure out how.

Some ideas I have thought about which may work

1. KNN to cluster negative cases
2. Overlay spatial grid and extract x number of samples from each grid square
3. Buffer analysis and randomly select within buffer

If anyone has recommendations on how to execute this in R it would be awesome.

thanks

Comment: I think this will get much more traction--and more informative responses--over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). This really isn't much of a programming question, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to answer here in case anyone else searches this.

I decided to go with a kmeans cluster and then added the cluster as a col to the dB and randomly sampled from clusters.

Code below!

```
    ##CLuster analysis set.seed(1) clusdb <- W_neg[c( 
                      "x_coor_farm", "y_coor_farm", 
                      "Area_Farm_SqM", "NatGrass_1km_buff",
                      "BioFor_1km_buff", "MixedFor_1km_buff", 
                      "Area_Cut_012", "Area_Cut_1224", "Area_Cut_2436",  "Cut_Count_012", "Cut_Count_1224", "Cut_Count_2436")]

##Write functuon to loop the algorithim kmean_withinss <- function(k) {   cluster <- kmeans(clusdb, k)   return (cluster$tot.withinss) }

# Set maximum cluster  max_k <-20 
# Run algorithm over a range of k  wss <- sapply(2:max_k, kmean_withinss)

#Dataframe of kmeans output to find optimal K elbow <-data.frame(2:max_k, wss)

#plot library(ggplot2) ggplot(elbow, aes(x = X2.max_k, y = wss)) +   geom_point() +   geom_line() +   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 20, by = 1))


#Optimal K = 8
#Re-run the model with optimal K

pc_cluster_2 <-kmeans(clusdb, 8) pc_cluster_2$cluster pc_cluster_2$centers pc_cluster_2$size

pc_cluster_2$totss pc_cluster_2$betweenss

pc_cluster_2$betweenss/pc_cluster_2$totss*100
#92% 

#Add col to dataframe W_neg$cluster <-pc_cluster_2$cluster


W_neg <- W_neg[c("TB2017",   "x_coor_farm", "y_coor_farm",    "Area_Farm_SqM", "NatGrass_1km_buff",   "BioFor_1km_buff", "MixedFor_1km_buff",    "Area_Cut_012", "Area_Cut_1224", "Area_Cut_2436", "Cut_Count_012", "Cut_Count_1224", "Cut_Count_2436", "cluster")]

ggplot(data = W_neg, aes(y = cluster)) +   geom_bar(aes(fill = TB2017)) +   ggtitle("Count of Clusters by Region") +   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

fviz_cluster(pc_cluster_2, data = scale(clusdb), geom = c("point"),ellipse.type = "euclid")
```